# Using Riemann–Stieltjes to compute an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, stieltjes-integral

I am calculating the following Riemann–Stieltjes integral

$$\int_0^bx \ d\left(\sum_{k=0}^{[x]}\frac{2^{k}}{k!}\right)$$

where $x>0$ and $[\,\cdot\,]$ is the floor function.

**My idea** is using the definition to write $$\int_0^bx \, d\left( \sum_{k=0}^{[x]} \frac{2^{k}}{k!} \right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ \left(\sum_{k=0}^{[x_i]}\frac{2^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{[x_{i-1}]} \frac{2^k}{k!}\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\frac{2^{[x_i]}}{[x_i]!},$$ here I use a partition $0= x_1<\cdots<x_n=b$, but I have no idea to tackle the last part I got.

**My second trying** is using the integration by parts and obtain $$\int_0^b x \ d\left(\sum_{k=0}^{[x]}\frac{2^{k}}{k!}\right)=b
    \sum_{k=0}^{[b]}\frac{2^k}{k!}-\int_0^b\sum_{k=0}^{[x]}\frac{2^k}{k!}dx.$$   I am not sure how to evaluate the last integral.

Any suggestion would be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: You could use the fact that if $$I(x)  = \begin{cases}0 & (x<0)\\ 1 & (x \geq 0)\end{cases},$$and if $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and continuous in $s \in (a,b)$, then $$\int_a^b fdI(x-s)=f(s).$$
This can be easily demonstrated using the definition (se, e.g. "baby" Rudin, Theorem 6.15, page 130).

Comment: Also, you should consider, I think, more carfully the last equality in your chain. Suppose all $x_i$'s are less than $1$. Then the quantity in parenthesis after the first equality is (correctly) $0$, independently of $i$, whereas the last quantity in the chain is strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I also think about using the integration by parts to tackle it and write it in the below. Could you please give me some suggestions? $$\int_0^b x   d (F(x))=b \sum_{k=0}^{[b]}\frac{2^k}{k!}-\int_0^b\sum_{k=0}^{[x]}\frac{2^k}{k!}dx, $$ where $F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{[x]}\frac{2^k}{k!}$. I am not sure how to evaluate the last integral. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you sketch the graph of $F(x)$? It may give you some other hints.

Comment: I would also check the hypotheses under which integration by parts is allowed.

Comment: @dfnu Yeah, I think I can plot the graph to solve the integral. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question, then. It may be interesting and useful for others to read it!